# Creating a Developer portal for Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have used azure b2c as my authorization server and would want to create a developer portal .  APIM developer portal provides me a subscription key but I am not getting the client id and secret required to communicate with my authorization server.  What is the recommended approach to way to create an application in Azure B2C via a program ?

Comment: Are you hoping to create an application or tenant?

You can get the client id when you've registered the app and click into it (app id = client id). You create the client secret by going into the keyvault and generating one.

These docs might be useful to you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant

|

Comment: I want to dynamically create a client application.  I am expecting APIM developer portal to generate a client id and secret as I do not want my end user to be using portal.azure.com directly.  What are the ways to achieve my goal ? I can see this feature available in apigee developer portal .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this through Microsoft Graph. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications

Please see the feature request thread. It is currently not possible to register these applications via a program. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19975480-programmatically-register-b2c-applications